# How to trigger action of actionable push notification in IOS if app is killed?

Tags: ios, swift, apple-push-notifications

I have an Actionable Push Notification with Accept or Decline actions. When the app is closed or killed , the actions does come but on clicking of them , the actions are not triggered in the code. I know didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method will be called, but what needs to be done in that ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is my answer about where to handle the action when user tap on push notification: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72325838/17286292

Then you can handle your actionable notification by following this:

```
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
            didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse,
            withCompletionHandler completionHandler: 
               @escaping () -> Void) {
   // Get the meeting ID from the original notification.
   let userInfo = response.notification.request.content.userInfo
        
   if response.notification.request.content.categoryIdentifier ==
              "MEETING_INVITATION" {
      // Retrieve the meeting details.
      let meetingID = userInfo["MEETING_ID"] as! String
      let userID = userInfo["USER_ID"] as! String
            
      switch response.actionIdentifier {
      case "ACCEPT_ACTION":
         sharedMeetingManager.acceptMeeting(user: userID, 
               meetingID: meetingID)
         break
                
      case "DECLINE_ACTION":
         sharedMeetingManager.declineMeeting(user: userID, 
               meetingID: meetingID)
         break
                
      case UNNotificationDefaultActionIdentifier,
           UNNotificationDismissActionIdentifier:
         // Queue meeting-related notifications for later
         //  if the user does not act.
         sharedMeetingManager.queueMeetingForDelivery(user: userID,
               meetingID: meetingID)
         break
                
      default:
         break
      }
   }
   else {
      // Handle other notification types...
   }
        
   // Always call the completion handler when done.
   completionHandler()
}
```

Ref: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/handling_notifications_and_notification-related_actions