# Handle tap on local notification when app is terminated - iOS - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, mobile, notifications

I want to handle tap on local notification, when the app is terminated, but there are no launch options in method `application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` and no call of method `application didReceive notification`.

I also tried to implement two methods of `UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate`:

1)Handles notification, **when app is in background, but not terminated**:

```
func userNotificationCenter(
    _ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
    didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse,
    withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void
)
```

2)And next handles notification, when app is in foreground:

```
func userNotificationCenter(
    _ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
    willPresent notification: UNNotification,
    withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void
)
```

Have no idea how to handle it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you tap on Push Notification on Notification Center.
OS launches your app (terminated before) then STILL delivers the action to this (Function 1)

```
func userNotificationCenter(
    _ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
    didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse,
    withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void
)
```

You can get the `notification` object from response like what you did.
But you may need to save temporary this data from the selected push notification, then handle it later when app is completely active with user.

Remember to call `completionHandler()` when you finish your logic. And, you must set `UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self`, before you `return true` in

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool`.
```

`self` here is your `AppDelegate`, which means you set UserNotification's delegate to a live object or initialized object.
It will be able to handle the above delegate function call (Function 1) to get your selected push notification's data.